# Delphi 2007 VCL Project Name Different from Compiled Exe Name?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Is there a way to have a Project named "SomeProject" that creates an EXE named "SomethingDifferent.exe"? In .net it is simple to have your project name be independent of your generated Assembly name, but I don't see how to do the equivalent in Delphi 2007.

Comment: You can change the file extension (e.g. to `.scr`)...

Comment: I think you could use post build events for that but I'm not sure are those available in D2007.

Comment: or add linux-style prefix/suffix/version decoration for libraries.

Comment: Post-build event is how I do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MSbuild with the Post-build event

[image]

for example you can create a copy of your exe with the  name which you want using a command like this

```
DEL  "$(OUTPUTDIR)SomethingDifferent.Exe"
COPY "$(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTFILENAME)" "$(OUTPUTDIR)SomethingDifferent.Exe"
```

Comment: Will this work for debugging?  For example, if you run, will the IDE pick up on the name change and run it? I don't see how it would, so it would break the IDE somewhat!

Comment: @David, no this not will work for debugging , but I don't see the point to change the exe name in debug mode.